# Load MIT-BIH Arrhythmia ECG database onto MATLAB

Tags: database, matlab, signal-processing, signals, data-mining

I am working on ECG signal processing using neural network which involves pattern recognition. 
As I need to collect all the data from Matlab to use it as test signal, I am finding it difficult to load it on to the Matlab.
I am using MIT Arrhythmia database [here](http://www.physionet.org/physiobank/database/mitdb/).

The signal needs to be indexed and stored as data structure in Matlab compatible format.
Presently, the signal is in `.atr` and `.dat` format.

How can you load MIT-BIH Arrhythmia database onto Matlab?

Comment: I removed you email address. It's better to put such info into your profile page rather than in your post as plain text, even if Gmail spam filtering does quite a good job.

Comment: I don't know what exactly you want to detect on the ECG signal but in my opinion the MIT-BIH database has a poor quality and I'd probably recommend you to find a different one.  From historical reasons it is some kind of academic standard, but if you don't need to compare your results with previous publications I'd use a different one. For example PTB is a good one (2 minute strips of 500 different patients, 12 lead ECG)

Comment: @Polda How can you describe PTB's quality? Can you confirm it to be AAMI standard? MIT-BIH is AAMI standard in ambulatory setting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use physionet [ATM](http://physionet.org/cgi-bin/atm/ATM) to get *.mat* files which are easier to work with.

In the *input* part select the desired leads, length, database and sample.

In the *toolbox* select `export as .mat`:

[image]

Then download the '.mat' file,

[image]

In order to open the file in MATLAB, here is a sample code:

```
load ('100m.mat')          % the signal will be loaded to "val" matrix
val = (val - 1024)/200;    % you have to remove "base" and "gain"
ECGsignal = val(1,1:1000); % select the lead (Lead I)
Fs = 360;                  % sampling frequecy
t = (0:length(ECGsignal)-1)/Fs;  % time
plot(t,ECGsignal)
```

and you will get,

[image]

However, If you were to read *annotation* files for *arrhythmia* or *QRS complexes* that would be another problem.

**Edit**

The *base* and *gain* come from the *info* file (second picture).
This file gives you various information regarding the ECG signal.

[image]

In the last sentence it says: *To convert from raw units to the physical units shown above, subtract 'base' and divide by 'gain'.*

Comment: Can you please explain your "base" and "gain" point more thoroughly. I added my answer below where I show the difference between your and the method where you do not those conversions.

Comment: Hi @Masi, thanks for your attention, as you want to download the `.mat` file, there is another file named `.info` in which it indicates: _To convert from raw units to the physical units shown above, subtract 'base' and divide by 'gain'`_.

Comment: Can you, please, include the link, citation and reference where they exactly say something about *base* and *gain*. Through the ATM tool, I cannot extract any info file. There may be a case that they have depreciated the info file here.

Comment: I think this is the source what are you recalling http://www.physionet.org/physiotools/matlab/rddata.m It does this base and gain removals in this code. I cannot find any other source for this thing.

Comment: @Masi, on my second picture in the post it says: _download these files:_ there is an _.info_ file, please check that file.

Comment: Please, see AmidJuneja's answer below. It is possible that you do not need to remove base and gain. His argument is solid. Silva's tree is a newer one of the toolbox. I opened a ticket about the confusion here https://github.com/ikarosilva/wfdb-app-toolbox/issues/119

Answer (score 4):

You need the program `rddata.m` (MATLab script) from [this website](http://www.physionet.org/physiotools/matlab/). The program can be found [here](http://www.physionet.org/physiotools/matlab/rddata.m). `rddata.m` is probably the only program you will need to read the ecg signals. I remember having used this program and database myself not too long ago.

Answer (score 2):

There is a tutorial for using matlab to read the data. [tutorial for matlab user](http://www.physionet.org/physiotools/matlab/)

1. install "The WFDB Toolbox for Matlab" from the link above. Add the folder of the toolbox to the path in matlab.
2. Download the ECG signal. Be sure to download `'.atr', '.dat' and '.hea'` together for the signal you are to deal with.
3. Command in matlab is as follows :

   `[tm,signal,Fs]=rdsamp( filename , 1 ) ; 
   [ann,type]=rdann( filename , 'atr' ) ;`

   Note: for signal '101', its name is '101'. And you can check the detail information about rdsamp and rdann from the tutorial.

Comment: Here about how to download those files locally http://stackoverflow.com/a/36706214/54964 so use `physionetdb("mitdb", 1);` before running `rdsamp(...)` to reduce network load and speed up your system. I am studying dbpath because there seem to be changes in different trees. I want that many projects can use local files to speed up the system. Here, the ticket https://github.com/ikarosilva/wfdb-app-toolbox/issues/117 in Ikaro's tree.

Answer (score 2):

So I read this answer 3 months ago and removed the base and gain. It turns out , i completely shifted my R-peaks in various directions, screwing up all my results. While I am not sure if doing this is necessary in matlab or not, DO NOT DO THIS if you are not preprocessing your signal in matlab. I was preprocessing my signal in python, and all I did to normalizae it was

```
val = val/2047  % (2047 is the max volt range of signals)
```

and used butterworth filters to remove artifacts  (range 0.5hz-45hz)

***CORRECTION***

The cutoff i selected is *0.5 to 45* not 5-15 as I previously reported. This cutoff preserves the QRS for various arrhythmias without adding too much noise

```
# baseline correction and bandpass filter of signals 
lowpass = scipy.signal.butter(1, highfreq/(rate/2.0), 'low') 
highpass = scipy.signal.butter(1, lowfreq/(rate/2.0), 'high') 

# TODO: Could use an actual bandpass filter 
ecg_low = scipy.signal.filtfilt(*lowpass, x=ecg) 
ecg_band = scipy.signal.filtfilt(*highpass, x=ecg_low)
```

Comment: Can you give your command about `butterworth` to remove artifacts in the range [0.5-45 Hz]`, please. I want to study it because the implementation varies in applications. I do not trust that the filtering is necessary here.

Comment: If you were doing HRV analysis of the signals, should you use the normalization `val=val/2047;`? I am using `sig=(sig-1024)/200;` at the moment, and really worrying that this is wrong. Your `val=val/2047` makes sense because max volt is 2^11 -1. I would like to understand why Rashid claims the other thing.

Comment: I opened a new ticket about the thing in Silva's tree because I really need an authoritative answer about the confusion. https://github.com/ikarosilva/wfdb-app-toolbox/issues/119

Comment: Hi Sorry i just saw this today
See the problem is that  if you are detecting R-peaks in your HRV analysis you don't wanna divide it by 200 because then each beat's R-peak position will be shifted and not synced.
I used the scipy,signal lib in python for butterworth. I am pasting my function in the next comment for your reference

Answer (score 0):

just use it

```
A=input('Enter Variable: ','s');
load(A);
a=(val(1,:));
b=fir1(100,[0.1,0.25],'stop');
y2=filter(b,1,a);
figure;
plot(y2);
```

Comment: When giving an answer it is preferable to give some explanation as to *WHY* your answer is the one.

Answer (score -1):

Use [ATM](http://physionet.org/cgi-bin/atm/ATM) to extract *.mat* as described by [Kamtal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25060867/54964) (now known Rashid).
However, note that to see the *.info* file in some cases, you need to click the arrow

[image]

After I pushed this forward to developers [here](https://github.com/ikarosilva/wfdb-app-toolbox/issues/119#issuecomment-230015542), we got improvements in the documentation [here](https://physionet.org/faq.shtml#isdigitalorphysical) in Section 4.

> If they are all integers in the range [-2^N, 2^N-1 ] or [ 0, 2^N ], they are probably digital. Compare the values to see if they are in the expected physiological range of the signal you are analyzing. For example, if the header states that the signal is an ECG stored in milivolts, which typically has an amplitude of about 2mV, a signal of integers ranging from -32000 to 32000 probably isn't giving you the physical ECG in milivolts...
>
> If they are not integers then they are physical. Once again you can quickly compare the values to see if they are in the expected physiological range of the signal you are analyzing.

### 0-9-10 wfdb - physical units

> We say that signals are in 'physical units' when the values are used to represent the actual real life values as closely as possible, although obviously everything on the computer is digital and discrete rather than analogue and continuous. This includes our precious 64 bit double precision floating point values, but this is as close as we can get and already very close to the actual physical values, so we refer to them as 'physical'.
>
> -
>
> For example, if a 15 bit signal is collected via a capturing device, Physionet will likely store it as a 16 bit signal. Each 16 bit block stores an integer value between -2^15 and 2^15-1, and using the gain and offset stated in the header for each channel, the original physical signal can be mapped out for processing.

The default units are now physical units where base and gain should be added stated in the header for each channel, so the physical signal can be mapped out for processing.

```
% rawUnits
%       A 1x1 integer (default: 0). Returns tm and signal as vectors
%       according to the following values:
%               rawUnits=0 - Uses Java Native Interface to directly fetch  data, returning signal in physical units with double precision.
%               rawUnits=1 -returns tm ( millisecond precision only! ) and signal in physical units with 64 bit (double) floating point precision
%               rawUnits=2 -returns tm ( millisecond precision only! ) and signal in physical units with 32 bit (single) floating point  precision
%               rawUnits=3 -returns both tm and signal as 16 bit integers (short). Use Fs to convert tm to seconds.
%               rawUnits=4 -returns both tm and signal as 64 bit integers (long). Use Fs to convert tm to seconds.
```

`rawUnits=1`, `rawUnits=2` use also physical units.
`rawUnits=3`, `rawUnits=4` use then again analog/digital units where you need to remove base and gain.
If you use `rawUnits=1` or `rawUnits=2`, you need to adjust for base and gain where `base = 1024` and `gain = 200`

```
# Kamtal's method in considering base and gain
load('201m.mat');
val = (val - 1024)/200;    % you have to remove "base" and "gain"
ECGsignal = val(1,16:950); % select the lead (Lead I)
```

See the .info file below where you can get the `base` and `gain`. There is also the unit `mV` which suggests the values should be near `2` after the base-gain operations.

### <0-9-9 wfdb - analog/digital units so base and gain by default; now only `rawUnits=3,4` for analog units

After selection ATM, you should be able to see the list where you can select *.info* file after the export as described in Kamtal's answer.
The *.info* file instructs to remove so-called *base* and *gain* from the data before use

```
Source: record mitdb/201  Start: [00:02:10.000]
val has 2 rows (signals) and 3600 columns (samples/signal)
Duration:     0:10
Sampling frequency: 360 Hz  Sampling interval: 0.002777777778 sec
Row     Signal  Gain    Base    Units
1       MLII    200     1024    mV
2       V1      200     1024    mV

To convert from raw units to the physical units shown
above, subtract 'base' and divide by 'gain'.
```

### Comparing wrong answers here! [Deprecated]

Kamtal (now called Rashid) answer is about the old wfdb system which used digital units without removal of base and gain

```
# Kamtal's method in considering base and gain
load('201m.mat');
val = (val - 1024)/200;    % you have to remove "base" and "gain"
ECGsignal = val(1,16:950); % select the lead (Lead I)

# Method without considering base and gain
load('201m.mat');
ECGsignal2 = val(1,16:950); 

# http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10502-image-overlay
imshow(imoverlay(ECGsignal, ECGsignal2, uint8([255,0,0])))
```

and you get the difference between my method and his method

[image]