# How to load MIT-BIH ECG database in R

Tags: r, matlab, signal-processing

I want to load the MIT BIH ECG format samples in R but I am having a hard time. There is a MATLAB tool for this as I have found here [Load MIT-BIH Arrhythmia ECG database onto MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6283929/how-to-load-mit-bih-ecg-database-onto-matlab)

Is there any way to get the sample ECG files to load in R?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try these steps:

1. Download [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/download.html), which is a free open-source version of Matlab.
2. In Octave, use the [physiotool](http://www.physionet.org/physiotools/matlab/) to load the ECG data.
3. In Octave, save the data that you want to a *.mat* file with [`save`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/save.html).
4. In R, use the [R.Matlab](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R.matlab/index.html) package.

Comment: They also have a tool `wfdb2mat` that will convert the db to `mat` without having to install Octave, if that's an issue for you. (Disclaimer: I haven't tested it, I'm just reading the docs at [physionet](http://www.physionet.org/physiotools/matlab/).)